# sslv3 alert illegal parameter using Net::HTTP in Ruby on Linux

Tags: ruby, ssl, https, openssl

I am attempting to use a remote system for user authentication. This chunk of code gets a response when I run it on MacOSX, but fails on my machine:

```
  def create
    uri = URI.parse('https://ourclient.example.com/')
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new('/login.jsp')
    request.set_form_data({'login_name' => params[:login], 'password' => params[:password]})
    response = http.request(request)
    puts "Response BODY: #{response.body.inspect}"
  end
```

Turning verify off gets rid of a warning on the Macs. On my machine, the http.request raises this exception:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert illegal parameter):
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:16:in `create'
```

I get the same behavior using IRB without Rails. I did a clean install of Fedora 14 yesterday, installed the required development tools and libraries. I'm using Ruby 1.9.2-p180, and Rails 3.0.4. I thought I might have had my libraries misconfigured (I had Fedora 12 that had been upgraded a few times), but this is now a new install.

The remote system is probably Microsoft's IIS, but I'm not certain of that. Perhaps I can use an older SSL protocol, but my Google-fu can't find the incantation.

I would appreciate any tips on resolving this issue. Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

how was created the ssl cert on the server?  self-signed or ca-signed?
which is the error you receive if you remove the VERIFY_NONE?

Comment: I'm checking on the server ssl setup. The warning I get is this: warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session

Comment: The certificate was created with Oracle Wallet Manager, then signed by Verisign, who is the signing authority.

Comment: i suppose the problem is in the ssl-certificate or the CN is not correct. have you tried with a different one? i've tested your code against a valid ssl-cert and i don't get any warning or error (even removing the verify_none). i'm on macosx.

Comment: I do not have access to the server. Thank you for giving this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

use Mechanize gem for it

```
gem install mechanize
```

and try

```
require 'mechanize'
page = Mechanize.new{|a| a.ssl_version, a.verify_mode = 'SSLv3', OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE}.get "**YOUR HTTPS LINK HERE**"
```